# Howto prevent XPath from return all if empty compare-variable?

Tags: xml, xpath

i have this construct to questionate my xml-document with a binding in xaml.

```
XPath="/doc/B/lists/entry[@value=(/doc/A/selectedValue)]"
```

If the path /doc/A/selectedValue is empty or did not exist all nodes of /doc/B/list/entry are returned. Is there a way to define that nothing should be returned in the case that /doc/A/selectedValue is empty or did not exists?

Hope somebody can help,

Greetings Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, not *all* B entires are returned, but the only empty ones. When there is no selected value, `/doc/A/selectedValue` returns the empty node set. When compared against a string (`@value`), then the empty node-set is converted to the empty string. Which means that your expression will be equal to

```
/doc/B/lists/entry[@value='']
```

To avoid that, you simply need to make sure that `/doc/A/selectedValue` is not empty:

```
/doc/B/lists/entry[/doc/A/selectedValue != '' and @value=/doc/A/selectedValue]
```

Note that like any XPath, `/doc/A/selectedValue` can return multiple nodes. More explicit and defensive is `/doc/A/selectedValue[1]`.

Comment: With several online-tests it works great, but in my XAML-Binding it always return the value of the content of the first path element.

Comment: I found the problem was a strip of datawaste in my sourcecode.